# Discrete cosine transform in htk is not the same with DCT in wiki

Tags: wiki, dct, htk

I saw the DCT in wiki:
[image]

but the DCT in htk book is :
[image]

These two formulas are not the same and I can't transform the first to the  second one,anybody tell me which one is used in mfcc?

Comment: There are differences in implementation caused by variety of standards. They are not significant for recognition accuracy but they lead to different values. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112204/why-do-mfcc-extraction-libs-return-different-values